# How to prevent require.js from adding .js extension at the end of mustache files

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I'm using requireJS to load scripts. While loading .mu (mustache) files, require will add a .js extension to the end of these paths. However this happens only for an IE whereas Chrome and FF work fine. i looked through some sources and found answers relevant to this issue. in one of the case its the noext plugin to be added:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'signalr-hubs': '/signalr/hubs?noext'
  }
});
```

that can be added to resolve this issue. however im not sure if adding only this above line will help solve the problem. Do i need to add any dependency plugin or anything to make it work??

here is my main.js:

```
require.config({
paths: {
    'signalr-hubs': '/signalr/hubs?noext',
    'text': 'path-to-text/text',
    'underscore': 'path-to-underscore/underscore',
    'jquery': 'path-to-jquery/jquery',
    'mustache':'path-to-mustache/mustache'
 }
});
```

Any ideass??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirejs is meant to load js files, which is why the js extension is presumed.

To load whatever other content type you need, you resort to plugins. And instead of passing the resource to requirejs, you pass it to the plugin.

Since mustache is somewhat parent to Handlebars you might want to try requirejs Handlebars plugin.

https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin

You would add

```
{ 
    ...
    'hbs' : 'vendor/requirejs-handlebars/hbs'
    ...
}
```

To your path config.

And eventually, load your template as

```
require(['hbs!template/something'], function(somethingFn) {
    ...
});
```

You see, the resource you pass to requirejs is hbs (hbs.js) and the resource you pass to hbs.js is the template textfile.

Hbs plugin presumes the  extension .hbs, but it's configurable.

Comment: Thanks, but im confused...so will adding the handlebar prevent adding the .js extension at the end while loading the files..?the above plugin didnt quite help..

Comment: No. Nothing will prevent adding js to the resource path. But when you use an plugin, whatever comes after ! Is an argument for the plugin, not for requirejs, and is therefore free to use another extension

Comment: ohh...sorry but still unclear on how to avoid the .js being added to the end of .mu files only. it renders fine for all .js files, but is a problem while rendering only mustache files, an it happens only in internet explorer..al other browsers fine!! what is the best way?? thanks

Comment: please paste the code where you are adding / requesting template.mu

Comment: amenadiel: sorry i'm little slow in understanding, but here is what i have for mustache file loading templates in main.js- http://jsfiddle.net/3x8xh2m7/, can you please let me know where your code fits in? Thanks!!